# Alternative to CASE WHEN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when

I have a table in SQL where the results look something like:

```
Number  |  Name     |  Name 2 
1       |  John     |  Derek  
1       |  John     |  NULL   
2       |  Jane     |  Louise 
2       |  Jane     |  NULL   
3       |  Michael  |  Mark   
3       |  Michael  |  NULL    
4       |  Sara     |  Paul    
4       |  Sara     |  NULL
```

I want a way to say that if Number=1, return Name 2 in new column Name 3, so that the results would look like:

```
Number  |  Name     |  Name 2  |  Name 3
1       |  John     |  Derek   |  Derek
1       |  John     |  NULL    |  Derek
2       |  Jane     |  Louise  |  Louise
2       |  Jane     |  NULL    |  Louise
3       |  Michael  |  Mark    |  Mark
3       |  Michael  |  NULL    |  Mark
4       |  Sara     |  Paul    |  Paul
4       |  Sara     |  NULL    |  Paul
```

The problem is that I can't say if Number=1, return Name 2 in Name 3, because my table has >100,000 records. I need it to do it automatically. More like "if Number is the same, return Name 2 in Name 3." I've tried to use a CASE statement but haven't been able to figure it out. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution 2, with lag (if your sql server version has lag function)

```
SELECT
    Number, Name, Name2,
    isnull(Name2, lag(Name2) OVER (PARTITION BY Number order by number)) Name3
FROM @sample;
```

Comment: Why did you post so many answers?  I mean, it worked, but it seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: This answer [isn't working in a simple demo](http://rextester.com/KZXHP25997) using the OP's test data.  If you can show that your answer is valid, I can remove the downvote.  Note that your use of LAG makes no sense, because there is no column to order to choose the non NULL record.

Comment: Lag is not a non sense, if not column to order, it take the row in order of insert....

Comment: But how do you even know the insertion order.  I would have no problem with one of your other answers being marked correct, just not this one.

Comment: How do i even know the insertion order.? I dont know, like you with your max.... You said "If you can show that your answer is valid, I can remove the downvote".... no? I show you that ^^

Comment: Interesting.  It seems to be working with a table variable, but not with a CTE.

Comment: i seems that too, i think order is not the same :)

Comment: So if the answer isn't working everywhere, should it be the accepted one?  Your other answers all look OK to me.  The OP should relabel then, I think.

Comment: The purpose is to answer the question as it is asked since the applicant does not specify. Each of my answers gives the expected result. And if it can not work in some cases (just like yours with the Max => see example provided above) it corresponds to the demand. Free to vote or not, at this point I will not spend my days there ...

Answer (score 3):

Empirically, this seems to work:

```
SELECT
    Number, Name, [Name 2],
    MAX([Name 2]) OVER (PARTITION BY Number) [Name 3]
FROM yourTable;
```

The idea here, if I interpreted your requirements correctly, is that you want to report the non `NULL` value of the second name for *all* records as the third name value.

Comment: with your solution, if there's a name in row 1 and row 2 for same Number you take the max in alphabetic order and not the first  row value... It the same "non sens" of utilisation of lag :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution 3, with group by

```
with maxi as(
SELECT Number, max(Name2) name3
FROM @sample
group by number, name
)
SELECT f1.*, f2.name3
FROM @sample f1 inner join maxi f2 on f1.number=f2.number
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

Solution 1, with row_number

```
declare @sample table (Number integer, Name varchar(50), Name2 varchar(50))
insert into @sample

select 1       ,  'John'     ,  'Derek' union all 
select 1       ,  'John'     ,  NULL   union all 
select 2       ,  'Jane'     ,  'Louise' union all 
select 2       ,  'Jane'     ,  NULL  union all 
select 3       ,  'Michael'  ,  'Mark' union all   
select 3       ,  'Michael'  ,  NULL   union all  
select 4       ,  'Sara'    , 'Paul'  union all   
select 4       ,  'Sara'     , NULL ; 

with tmp as ( 
select *, row_number() over(partition by number order by number) rang 
from @sample 
)
select f1.Number, f1.Name, f1.Name2, f2.Name2 as Name3
from tmp f1 inner join tmp f2 on f1.Number=f2.Number  and f2.rang=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 4, with cross apply

```
SELECT *
FROM @sample f1 cross apply
(
select top 1 f2.Name2 as Name3 from @sample f2 
where f2.number=f1.number and f2.Name2 is not null
) f3
```